# Error when I try provide the implemenation for the interface DomainMapper<PlayerDataEntity, List<PlayerModel>>

Tags: android, dagger-2

```
Dagger 2.32
```

I am getting the following error when I try provide the implemenation for the interface `DomainMapper<PlayerDataEntity, List<PlayerModel>>`

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] me.androidbox.data.mappers.DomainMapper<? super me.androidbox.data.entities.PlayerDataEntity,? extends java.util.List<me.androidbox.domain.models.PlayerModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface ApplicationComponent {
                ^
      me.androidbox.data.mappers.DomainMapper<? super me.androidbox.data.entities.PlayerDataEntity,? extends java.util.List<me.androidbox.domain.models.PlayerModel>> is injected at
          me.androidbox.data.requests.imp.RequestPlayersImp(…, domainMapper)
      me.androidbox.data.requests.imp.RequestPlayersImp is requested at
          me.androidbox.app.application.ApplicationComponent.requestPlayersImp()
```

Following classes:

```
class RequestPlayersImp @Inject constructor(
        private val footballServices: FootballServices,
        private val domainMapper: DomainMapper<PlayerDataEntity, List<PlayerModel>>
) : PlayersInteractor {
}

class DomainMapperImp @Inject constructor(): DomainMapper<PlayerDataEntity, List<PlayerModel>> {    
}

@Module
interface PlayerModule {

    @Binds
    fun provideRequestPlayersImp(requestPlayersImp: RequestPlayersImp): PlayersInteractor

    @Binds
    fun provideFootballServices(mockFootballServices: MockFootballServices): FootballServices

    @Binds
    fun provideDomainMapper(domainMapperImp: DomainMapperImp): DomainMapper<PlayerDataEntity, List<PlayerModel>>
}
```

However, I can solve the issue by creating a new Interface:

```
interface DomainMapperEntityToDomain : DomainMapper<PlayerDataEntity, List<PlayerModel>>
```

And using that as below. Everything compiles ok

```
class RequestPlayersImp @Inject constructor(
        private val footballServices: FootballServices,
        private val domainMapper:  DomainMapperEntityToDomain
) : PlayersInteractor {
}

class DomainMapperImp @Inject constructor(): DomainMapperEntityToDomain  {  
}

@Binds
fun provideDomainMapper(domainMapperImp: DomainMapperImp): DomainMapperEntityToDomain
```

My questions is why can't I use the following interface:

```
DomainMapper<PlayerDataEntity, List<PlayerModel>>
```

Many thanks for any advice,

data classes just incase they are important

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class PlayerDataEntity(
        val data: List<PlayerEntity>
)

data class PlayerModel(
    val playerId: Int,
    val firstname: String,
    val lastname: String,
    val birthday: String,
    val age: Int,
    val weight: Int,
    val height: Int,
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```kotlin
DomainMapper<@JvmSuppressWildcards PlayerDataEntity, @JvmSuppressWildcards List< @JvmSuppressWildcards PlayerModel>>
```

instead of:

```kotlin
DomainMapper<PlayerDataEntity, List<PlayerModel>>
```

you can find more details about it in [this link](https://adavis.info/2017/08/jvmsuppresswildcards-biggest-annoyance-kotlin.html)